# Carry message through a website using PHP OOP

Tags: php, oop, static, messaging

I am a beginner to PHP and i want to make a static method that if its argument is empty it'll show the message. If not, it'll set the given message to a static variable for later use. But when i call the method to set the message, and then call it in another page to show the message. Nothing appear.

Here's my portion of code for this "session.php" :

```
   class Session {

            public static $message; 


            public static function notify($message = ""){
                if(!empty($message)){
                    self::$message = $message;                    
                } else {                        
                    return self::$message;
                }
            }
}

    $session = new Session();
```

"add_user.php" :

```
<?php       
    require_once '../helper/session.php';       
?>

<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {        

        $user->username = $_POST["username"];
        $user->password = $_POST["password"];
        $user->first_name = $_POST["first_name"];
        $user->last_name = $_POST["last_name"];
        if($result = $user->add_user()){
            Session::notify("New user added");
            redirect_to("../view/login.php");
        } else { Session::notify("Cannot add new user"); }

    }
?>
```

"login.php" :

```
<?php 
    require_once "../control/add_user.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheet/login.css" />
        <title>Welcome to Harmony</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h2>Harmony</h2>
        </header>

        <section>
            <div id="formStyle">
                <h3>Login or Signup:</h3>
                <form action="login.php" method="post">

                    <p><label for="username">Username: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username"/></p>

                    <p><label for="password">Password: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"/></p>

                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
                    <input type="button" name="sign_up" value="Sign up" onClick="parent.location='add_user.php'">
                </form>
                            <?php echo Session::notify();  ?>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't really writing to the session, now are you?
You should create two more methods for getting and setting the variables in the actual session. After the redirect, your message dissapears, because it is only saved on script execution.

```
function set_notification($message) {
$_SESSION['notification'] = $message; }
function get_notification() {
if(!empty($_SESSION['notification'])) {
return $_SESSION['notification']; }
```

Something like that :)

Of course, for sessions to work, you should do a session_start() call in the beginning of the script. read more about them [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php)

Answer (score 1):

HTTP by nature is shared-nothing, so anything you do in one request is not available to any other request. You will need to use a shared datastore to persist these messages.

A database, memcache, even a text file on the server (assuming you are operating on a single server and are not load balancing multiple) are all choices.

You can use cookies on the client side to persist a small amount of data. But keep in mind its not a secure solution (without using encryption) and you are limited in the amount of data you can store in cookies.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP - and PHP - is stateless. You need to use session variables to track data across sessions

http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php